# how to use find algorithm for a vector

Tags: c++, vector, find

If the vector's element is a **pair** type, like `vector<pair<int, double>>`. I want to the find algorithm focus on the first element of my vector. How can I do this?

For example, the following is my data:

```
<1, 2>

<3, 5>

<3, 4>
...
```

I want the find 1 in the first column.

Thanks,

Comment: you need to clear up your question. Do you want 1. the lowest value in the first column (i.e. the first member of the pair), 2. an arbitary value to look for as the value of the first member of the pair. The solutions are wildly different as you can see below. Also, if the vector is already in sorted order, what's wrong with the begin iterator?

Answer (score 4):

Going out of my way to make the answer *generic*:

```
template <typename K>
struct match_first
{
    const K _k; match_first(const K& k) : _k(k) {}
    template <typename V>
        bool operator()(const std::pair<K, V>& el) const 
    {
        return _k == el.first;
    }
};
```

use it like, e.g.

```
it = std::find_if(vec.begin(), vec.begin(), match_first<int>(1));

if (it!=vec.end())
{ 
    // found
}
```

Comment: And if the first (lowest/smallest) key is 4... or 28... or -212... or totally unknown? (I'm making an assumption that the lowest key is the first.)

Comment: @Sani: The question doesn't mention _lowest_ or _minimum_ or whatnot. My code searches for a specific value, and I took `1` as the value from the question sample. But you can use `match_first<int>(4)`,  `match_first<int>(28)`,  `match_first<int>(-212)` or even  `match_first<int>(totally_unknown)` just fine

Comment: True for all but match_first<int>(totally_unknown). You cannot find something you don't know to look for.

Comment: @Why not? Have you not heard of variables before? Just try it, e.g. `int totally_unknown; cin >> totally_unknown;` reads it from the console

Comment: OK... let me explain something to you about programming... There are variables and there are algorithms... You can set a value for a variable... But that value has to be known... If you don't know the value you are looking for you cannot set that value to the variable... Here is where algorithms comes in... If all you know is that you want to find the smallest key value then that is what you will search for... not a specific predetermined value... And this is what an algorithm does... ;)

Comment: Ok, I guess you're not joking. May you happily find all the lowest values you can find in peace.

Comment: Actually, if you want to go out of your way to be *generic…* `template<class K> struct match_first_type { K k; match_first_type(K k) : k(k) {} template<class T> bool operator()(T const &x) { return x.first == k; } }; template<class K> match_first_type<K> match_first(K k) { return k; }` Use as match_first(1) without having to specify int as the template argument.

Comment: @Sani: it is because I have looked at some of your other answers that I respect you enough to not shout at you. However, honestly, I think you may have been a little over-board here, probably because C++ is perhaps not your area of expertise. No harm done. We're all here to help

Comment: Thanks @Fred :) I was playing with the thought, but I decided against including it because I had a hunch that my answer would look ... intimidating enough without the extra lines. But, yeah, the extra credit totally!

Comment: @sehe: Well... I wouldn't say I'm an expert on C++ but I do know my way around it and use it professionally now and then... Regardless the question wasn't tagged with C++ at the time I wrote my answer... But the REAL question should be what the OP is really asking here... My assumption was that he wanted to find the lowest/smallest key... Other assumptions are the first key-value pair or a specific key-value pair with a known key value... All different assumption are correct since the OP does not specify the "rules"... I just wanted to make a point that you made an assumption just as I did...

Comment: @sehe, actually Sani has a point (not about his programming comment), but about what the OP is after - it's not abundantly clear wheher the OP is looking for an algorithm to search for an arbitary value or what he considers the first element (which could be interpreted as lowest).

Comment: @Nim good point: let the OP decide. Meanwhile, I'm in good company of people who immediately 'knew' (perhaps, wrongly) that the OP meant `pair::first` so I won't have to feel embarrassed when it turns out I was wrong. Cheers

Comment: It doesn't (for me atleast) matter who is right or wrong. Only that the OP gets the answer he/she is looking for. All answers are correct until the OP specifies the "rules" in more detail.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using newer C++ compiler you could write

```
int value_to_find = 1;
auto it = find_if( v.begin(), v.end(), [=]( const pair<int,double> &p ) { return p.first == value_to_find; } );
if ( it != v.end() ) {
    // found!
    }
```

Comment: And if the "value" of the first (lowest/smallest) key is unknown? You're assuming that the first key is always 1. It could be 4, 8, -212 or whatever...

Comment: @Sani Huttunen, nothing in C++ lambda syntax prevents using a variable.  I only pointed out this example as a very concise way which doesn't require implementing an entire class (or rather lets the compiler do it).

Comment: True in most parts. But if you do not know the value of the key you are looking for this approach won't work.

Comment: @Sani Huttunen, I'm assuming that by "first element" he means pair<int,double>::first not v[0]

Comment: @MerickOWA, that is an equally correct assumption as mine. You return the key-value pair where the key is 1 (or whatever predetermined value you choose). You do assume that that the first key value is known. What if it is unknown? Granted the OP lacks some crucial information to properly determine what the OP is asking for.

Comment: Actually, in 0x I'd write: `for (auto &x : v) { if (x.first == 1) { do_stuff_with(x); /*break if you only want to find the first instead of all*/ } }`

Comment: @Fred thats awesome, I didn't know about the new 'for' syntax

Answer (score 1):

why not use a `multimap<int, double>` instead of a `vector`? its `.find(1)` would yield an iterator that would give the pair `pair<int, double>(1,2)` as in your example; http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Multimap.html

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of language/platform this is what you need to do (in pseudo code):

```
min = MAXIMUM_INTEGER_VALUE
minValue = 0
for each (element in vector)
  if (element.key < min)
    min = element.key
    minValue = element.value
  end if
loop for
```

Now you should have the smallest key and it's value in min and minValue respectively.
However you COULD in the extreme case of when all keys are equal to MAXIMUM_INTEGER_VALUE end up with the wrong result. The solution would be to assign the first elements value to minValue instead of 0 during initialization.

Comment: Where does the question mention finding a minimum value? Also, encouraging to implement a new sort/find algorithm is ... bad advise

Comment: Nowhere... this is an assumption I made... Since the keys are 1, 3, 3 I assumed the example keys are not in anyway important to how the mentioned algorithm should work. The algorithm should find the smallest key value (assumption) according to the example.

Comment: Are you sure he wants to find a specific key? And why the downvote to a generic, working algorithm?

Comment: Acutally having looked at the OP's question, there is a case for this solution, intent is not clear. The OP does not specifically say he is looking for an arbitary value, just the first (whatever that means to the OP). So +1 for now...